# Calculating Impedance for capacitor in AC circuit with some undefined waveform

Tags: capacitor, resistors, ac

I need to set up equations for some simple AC circuit. The problem is that I dont know the formula, definition for the resistance.

I know for the 1/2*PI()*f*C, but I think this is only valid for the sin, cos, waveforms.

My question: is the formel 1/2*PI*f*C valid for other waveforms, and if not, what is the most basic formel.

Thank you

Comment: Calculate the reactance of odd harmonics, up to the one that will be  equal to the ohmic part of the ciurcuit (cut-off frequency Xc=R).

Comment: Your question title is somewhat different than your question, so unless I misunderstand you, your question is just about finding the generalized impedance.

It's only valid for sine waves. I actually had that problem about a week ago. It has to do with the RMS power through the capacitor, which is different for a squarewave or sawtooth than a sinewave, so the corner (or cutoff) frequency will be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try THE most basic formula for a capacitor namely Q = CV which leads to: -

\$\dfrac{dQ}{dt} = C \dfrac{dV}{dt}\$

and this leads to: -

\$ I = C \dfrac{dV}{dt}\$

In other words if you know the formula for the applied voltage, V, you can differentiate it and derive an expression for current AND, V divided by current could be described as the dynamic impedance for the capacitor. It's a bit unusual to state it this way but it may help.

Answer (score 2):

The most basic form is 1/jwC
If you can determine the fourier transform of the waveform you are subjecting it to you can approach this analytically.

Or use some form of simulation package

Comment: Ok thanks, but I have some formel that goes like this U = 1/C integral from 0 to period i(t). Can you explain to m what is this

Answer (score 2):

The formula you give is only valid for steady state and sinusoidal waveforms, and it only the gives you the magnitude (which happens to be the imaginary part for a capacitor or inductor) of the answer (it will fall apart if you stick a resistor in series and try to calculate the behavior).

The most general form is \$ Z_c \$ = \$ 1 \over s \cdot C\$, valid for any waveform, periodic or not. But you'll need to know complex analysis including Laplace transforms to use it. You can think of Laplace transforms as moving you from the time domain to the frequency domain (and back again for the inverse transforms).

You could also write out and try and solve the differential equations directly, if your skills lie in that area.

Rather than trying to solve your problem analytically, you may wish to simulate it with one of the free SPICE simulators available, such as Circuitlab on this site, or LTSpice.

Answer (score 1):

All periodic waveforms can be expressed as a summation of weighted sinusoids. See [Fourier Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) for more information on that.

This means that the impedance of a capacitor for a sine wave is also the impedance for any other periodic signal, because those periodic signals can also be represented as a bunch of sine waves [superimposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) on each other.